# How to open ports to local network in MacOS?

Tags: macos, networking

I'm searching for an answer about: how to open ports to local network in MacOS?

Basically, what I'm trying to do, is to run a local web server on flask, in my MacOS, and what I wanna do is to enter to that server with my phone of other computer connected to the same local network.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? This should be rather straightforward. Did you run into any problems?

Comment: @FiliusPatris I've tried to turn on the Firewall to allow all the traffic but nothing happened...

Comment: Having the firewall turned on will trigger a system prompt to check if you want to allow the program (python) to open incoming network connections (at least this is what happens sometimes for node), but only once per unique binary. Have you accepted this? And some more information would be useful: Do you open the correct port on your phone? Are you in the same network? Do you get any errors? What is the command you used? Does it work on localhost?

Comment: @FiliusPatris Yes to all the questions. I've accepted to open incoming network connections. I'm opening the correct port in my phone (5000). I'm in the same network. I'm not seeing any error because I'm not receiving the request in the flask server, my phone seems to not reaching the computer. And yes, it work on localhost, I mean, from the same computer that I'm running the flask server I can reach the server.